# A question about book <Introduction to Topological Manifolds> by John Lee

Tags: algebraic-topology

The author first proved the following important theorem - "Unique Lifting Property of the Circle"[image]

Then, the author proved the following corollary.

[image]

My question is: if corollary 8.6's assumption underlined by a red line is wrong. When two lifts $\tilde{f_0},\tilde{f_1}$
have the same initial point, they agree at the point $0$ of $[0,1]$. Then they should be identically equal by Theorem 8.3!

Comment: $\tilde{f_1}$ and $\tilde{f_2}$ are not lifts of the same map, so Theorem 8.3 doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no issue. Theorem 8.3 describes lifts of the *same* path, whereas Corollary 8.6 describes lifts of distinct paths.

Comment: Yes. I just figured out and was writing an answer when I saw your answer. Theorem 8.3 is for a **single** function. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Happy reading.